# Setting up an ssl connection in airflow

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, airflow

I'm setting up [airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/project.html) on a server. The airflow webserver is currently running as a daemon and I have established some database connections that do not need ssl keys/certificates. My next step will be to connect to a database where ssl keys/certificates are needed. I have two questions:

**Questions:**

- Where should I specify which ssl certificates to use? I set the previous connections up in the UI, but there seems to be no option for the use of ssl. I've tried to find [some documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#ssl) regarding the use of ssl certificates in airflow, but all I've read thus far concerns securing the webserver and not setting up database connections with ssl (as far as I can understand). I've tried to find an answer to my question in previous posts but they again seem to concern ssl for the webserver: [openssl for apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275435/setting-up-two-ways-ssl-on-apache-airflow).
- How do I get the ssl certificates from my computer (mac) to the server (ubuntu)?

**Edit:** I have at least solved the last part of the problem. I pushed the ssl files to a repository and clone that repository from the server.

Comment: I am a bit confused. You talk about SSL but you seem to be using `ssh-copy-id` that is used to copy SSH key to remote machine.

Comment: @kaxil Thanks for pointing that out. Edited my question :)

Comment: If I understood you right, you want to use something like an SqlSensor() with a DB that requires SSL for connection. Can you describe in more detail what you want to do and to what database you want to connect?